# How can I compare 2 dates converting from broken-down time to calendar time?

Tags: c, time

I am asking what exactly what title says. Obviously something goes wrong in my following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    struct tm t1 , t2;

    t1.tm_sec = 0;
    t1.tm_min = 0;
    t1.tm_hour = 0;
    t1.tm_isdst = -1;
    t2 = t1;

    printf("Enter 2 dates:\n");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d" , &t1.tm_mday , &t1.tm_mon , &t1.tm_year ,//   Sorry for 
                                &t2.tm_mday , &t2.tm_mon , &t2.tm_year);// lazy coding here
    time_t tm1 , tm2;
    tm1 = mktime(&t1);
    tm2 = mktime(&t2);


    printf("%d" , (int) difftime(tm1 , tm2));
}
```

The output is always zero. The output when I try to run it like this is:

```
C:\Users\...>program
Enter 2 dates:
3/2/2016 12/2/2017
0
```

Comment: One problem is that you've not recoded the year as `year - 1900` nor the month as `month - 1` — so you are looking at wholly different dates from the values you expected.  That does not explain the result of 0, though.  Have you tried printing `tm1` and `tm2` (cast to `long long` and format accordingly)?  Have you tried checking the return value from `scanf()`?  If it is not 6, you've got problems.

Comment: What is the `year - 1900` and  `month -1` thing? Enlighten me please.

Comment: See C11 [§7.27.1 Components of time](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1).  The encoding of `tm_year` and `tm_mon` is not what you're expecting.

Comment: However, even with that check added, I get a result `-32310000`, which is in the right ballpark (π seconds is a nanocentury, so there a 10π megaseconds in a year).  So, I cannot reproduce.  I'm testing on a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.6, though, whereas you're using Windows.

Comment: Do you know whether you have 32-bit or 64-bit `time_t` values?  If you have 32-bit values, you've got major overflow problems — the unadjusted years are 3916 and 3917, so a 32-bit `time_t` will have rolled over a few times.  You run into problems starting with 2038 (which should be encoded as 138) — in fact, after 0x7FFFFFFF = 2147483647 = 2038-01-19 03:14:07Z.

Comment: I'm getting right results, cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MrBens — what environment are you testing in?  Do you know whether your `time_t` values are 32-bit or 64-bit values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your problems are a consequence of two factors:

1. You don't subtract 1900 from the year values entered by the user, nor do you subtract 1 from the month number — see C11 [§7.27.1 components of time](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1) for information about the slightly weird encoding for the `tm_year` and `tm_mon` elements of `struct tm`.
2. Your system uses 32-bit `time_t`, rather than 64-bit `time_t`.

Here's a variant of your code, running on a 64-bit system (a MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.6, using GCC 9.3.0).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static void dump_time(const char *tag, time_t t);
static void dump_struct_tm(const char *tag, const struct tm *tm);

int main(void)
{
    struct tm t1 = { 0 };  /* Probably not essential, but a good idea */

    printf("sizeof(time_t) = %d\n", (int)sizeof(time_t));

    t1.tm_sec = 0;
    t1.tm_min = 0;
    t1.tm_hour = 0;
    t1.tm_isdst = -1;
    struct tm t2 = t1;

    printf("Enter 2 dates:\n");
    int n = scanf("%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d", &t1.tm_mday, &t1.tm_mon, &t1.tm_year,
                  &t2.tm_mday, &t2.tm_mon, &t2.tm_year);
    if (n != 6)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to read two dates (n = %d)\n", n);
        return 1;
    }
    struct tm t3 = t1;
    struct tm t4 = t2;

    time_t tm1, tm2;
    tm1 = mktime(&t1);
    tm2 = mktime(&t2);

    dump_struct_tm("t1", &t1);
    dump_struct_tm("t2", &t2);
    dump_time("time-1", tm1);
    dump_time("time-2", tm2);
    printf("%d\n", (int) difftime(tm1, tm2));

    t3.tm_year -= 1900;
    t3.tm_mon  -= 1;
    t4.tm_year -= 1900;
    t4.tm_mon  -= 1;
    time_t tm3 = mktime(&t3);
    time_t tm4 = mktime(&t4);

    dump_struct_tm("t3", &t3);
    dump_struct_tm("t4", &t4);
    dump_time("time-3", tm3);
    dump_time("time-4", tm4);
    printf("%d\n", (int) difftime(tm3, tm4));

    return 0;
}

static void dump_time(const char *tag, time_t t)
{
    char buffer[32];
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&t));
    printf("%s = %lld (%s)\n", tag, (long long)t, buffer);
}

static void dump_struct_tm(const char *tag, const struct tm *tm)
{
    printf("%s: year = %5d, month = %2d, day = %2d, "
           "hour = %2d, minute = %2d, second = %2d, DST = %d\n",
           tag, tm->tm_year, tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_mday,
           tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec, tm->tm_isdst);
}
```

The two dumping functions are illustrative of a handy technique I use when debugging — a function that dumps a structure, along with a tag that identifies what the code is dumping this time.

When run (as `date37`, compiled from `date37.c`), I get:

```
$ date37
sizeof(time_t) = 8
Enter 2 dates:
3/2/2016 12/2/2017
t1: year =  2016, month =  2, day =  3, hour =  0, minute =  0, second =  0, DST = 0
t2: year =  2017, month =  2, day = 12, hour =  0, minute =  0, second =  0, DST = 1
time-1 = 61415132400 (3916-03-03 00:00:00)
time-2 = 61447442400 (3917-03-12 00:00:00)
-32310000
t3: year =   116, month =  1, day =  3, hour =  0, minute =  0, second =  0, DST = 0
t4: year =   117, month =  1, day = 12, hour =  0, minute =  0, second =  0, DST = 0
time-3 = 1454482800 (2016-02-03 00:00:00)
time-4 = 1486882800 (2017-02-12 00:00:00)
-32400000
$
```

The difference between the two values that result from `difftime()` is 90000 seconds, the number of seconds in a day (86400) plus the number of seconds in an hour (3600).  The "1 day" component is because 2016 was a leap year and the difference spans 2016-02-29, but even though 3916 is a leap year, the difference is between two dates in March in consecutive years, which doesn't span 3916-02-29.  The "1 hour" component is because the time zone I'm in, US/Mountain or America/Denver (UTC-07:00 in standard time, UTC-06:00 in daylight saving time), switches between winter time (standard time) and summer time (daylight saving time) on Sunday 3917-03-11 at 02:00.  Note that `strftime()` assumes local time; using `gmtime()` instead of `localtime()` changes the apparent time values.

Try this code on your machine.  I expect that you're running into overflows because you have 32-bit `time_t` and the dates in the fourth millennium have overflowed.  I would not be surprised to find that `mktime()` returns `-1` for both dates in the first (uncorrected) fragment because the values cannot be represented accurately (and the difference between `-1` and `-1` is indeed `0`).

If you have 32-bit `time_t` values, you run into trouble after a `time_t` value reaches:

```
0x7FFFFFFF = 2147483647 = 2038-01-19 03:14:07Z (aka UTC)
```

A machine with 64-bit `time_t` does not run into that problem.

Comment: `mktime(&t1)` may rely on more than the 7 used members here of `struct tm`.  Recommend `struct tm t1 = { 0 };` for complete initialization.

Comment: Which extra members do you think it can use?  It's not altogether a bad idea to initialize `struct tm t1` to all zeros, but it is only allowed by the standard to use the 7 members as far as I understand the specification.

Comment: C has "The tm structure shall contain at least the following members" (the well known 9) and for `mktime()` "The original values of the tm_wday and tm_yday components of the structure are ignored", thus members like `.nano_seconds`, `.utc_offset`, etc. may contribute in `mktime()`.

Comment: Not wholly convinced, but I shouldn't even be awake, let alone arguing the niceties.  I think the standard discusses the behaviour in terms of the elements it standardizes; other elements are not allowed to affect the behaviour significantly.

Comment: Yeah you were right, sir. My `sizeof(time_t)` is 4 and I got overflows (and bunch of garbage) in the first half.  I appreciate your help